# Adding multiple items to a form via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

GOAL:

Dynamically add form elements—in this case a number of checkboxes—to a form.

PROBLEM:

My code produces only 1 checkbox.

ASSUMPTION:

1. Scope issue.
2. Once an html element is created and then attached to another element in the DOM or vDOM using jQuery, it cannot be reused again and I need to build another.

CODE:

```
$pform = $('<form/>'); // Create a form element.
$pform_checkbox = $('<input/>').attr('type','checkbox'); // Create checkbox element.
$('body').append($pform); // Add form element within the body element.

//Goal is to add 5 checkboxes to the form.
//The result is only one checkbox is added. Why?
for (var x = 0; x<5; x++){
    //creating the checkbox element here will give me the proper result. 
    //$pform_checkbox = $('<input/>').attr('type','checkbox')
    $pform.append($pform_checkbox);
}
```

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/7ykjhdzd/

Comment: Well, you're only creating one checkbox, so no suprise there ?

Comment: Your second assumption is somewhat correct though, once you've created an element, appending it multiple times just moves the same element, it doesn't magically spawn new elements.

Comment: And you already know the solution, creating elements or cloning the one you have inside the loop.

Comment: I'm confused; I was under the impression that $pform_checkbox will always evaluate to an input element, so my loop keeps 'appending' an instance of that checkbox to the existing form.

Comment: your fiddle works when u uncomment the 2nd line in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `$('<input/>')`, you are [telling jQuery to create an `input` DOM element](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2). It only creates one `input`.

In order to create a copy of that input, you can use [`.clone`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). If you don't clone it first, you'll simply be re-appending the same element (which just moves it to a new location).

From the [`.append`](https://api.jquery.com/append/) documentation:

> You can also select an element on the page and insert it into another:
>
> ```
> $( ".container" ).append( $( "h2" ) );
> ```
>
> If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location
>   elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):

The following code demonstrates that `.append` simply changes the position of an element in the DOM tree:

```js
$("#div2").append($("#text"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Hello <span id="text">World</span></div>
<div id="div2">Div2: </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create the checkbox inside the loop:

```
$pform = $('<form/>'); // Create a form element.
$('body').append($pform); // Add form element within the body element.

for (var x = 0; x<5; x++){
    $pform_checkbox = $('<input/>').attr('type','checkbox')
    $pform.append($pform_checkbox);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused because after 
`$pform_checkbox = $('<input/>').attr('type','checkbox');`

$pform_checkbox becomes a reference to the actual checkbox so without redeclaring it each time you go through the iteration its just trying to append the same checkbox to the form.